# Disable part of SeekBar

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Is it possible to create disabled part of SeekBar? In need to create such component.
[image]

The main problem is to disable part of my SeekBar with changing color of this disabled part.

I spend a few hours to find out how to do it but didn't find any relation in source code and documentation.

Comment: You Probably need to create a Custom Seek bar for it ..  Look into Some Open source available Custom Seek bar library and Try to Modify it ..

Comment: Yeah unfortunately seems like this is the only way.